# Don't know the correct rust target for system type arm-unknown-linux-androideabi. Installing scrapy on termux

Tags: scrapy, termux

I tried to instal scrapy on android via termux. Reciving next error, and as i am quite new in that type of coding, i cant solve tge problem myself. Strugling around 5 days... Help please.

What I've done:

> ~ $ source venv/bin/activate                      (venv) ~ $ pip3 install scrapy

I recive:

`````
  Using cached Scrapy-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (254 kB)
Collecting itemloaders>=1.0.1
  Using cached itemloaders-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting queuelib>=1.4.2
  Using cached queuelib-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.1.3 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (5.4.0)
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5
  Using cached PyDispatcher-2.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9.1
  Using cached cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Twisted[http2]>=17.9.0
  Using cached Twisted-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-22.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting itemadapter>=0.1.0
  Using cached itemadapter-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.22.0)
Collecting lxml>=3.5.0
  Using cached lxml-4.7.1-cp310-cp310-linux_armv8l.whl
Collecting protego>=0.1.15
  Using cached Protego-0.1.16-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting h2<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached h2-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting parsel>=1.5.0
  Using cached parsel-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=2.0
  Using cached cryptography-36.0.1.tar.gz (572 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting service-identity>=16.0.0
  Using cached service_identity-21.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp310-cp310-linux_armv8l.whl
Collecting hpack<4,>=3.0
  Using cached hpack-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting hyperframe<6,>=5.2.0
  Using cached hyperframe-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting jmespath>=0.9.5
  Using cached jmespath-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from parsel>=1.5.0->scrapy) (1.16.0)
Collecting pyasn1-modules
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.1.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted[http2]>=17.9.0->scrapy) (4.0.1)
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1
  Using cached hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting incremental>=21.3.0
  Using cached incremental-21.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting Automat>=0.8.0
  Using cached Automat-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting constantly>=15.1
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting priority<2.0,>=1.1.0
  Using cached priority-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.1.3->scrapy) (58.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted[http2]>=17.9.0->scrapy) (3.3)````

And then the issue happened:

````Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml) ... error. error: subprocess-exited-with-error````

````× Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running egg_info
      writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.APACHE'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.BSD'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
      running build_ext
      running build_rust````

**=============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================**

      error: Don't know the correct rust target for system type arm-unknown-linux-androideabi. Please set the CARGO_BUILD_TARGET environment variable.
      [end of output]

And i realy cant figure out how to set up that envirement variable in that situation...

If i write: `rustc --print target-list`

I get thos list, and i cant figure out what to do next.

````aarch64-apple-darwin
aarch64-apple-ios
aarch64-apple-ios-macabi
aarch64-apple-ios-sim
aarch64-apple-tvos
aarch64-fuchsia
aarch64-kmc-solid_asp3
aarch64-linux-android
aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
aarch64-unknown-freebsd
aarch64-unknown-hermit
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32
aarch64-unknown-linux-musl
aarch64-unknown-netbsd
aarch64-unknown-none
aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat
aarch64-unknown-openbsd
aarch64-unknown-redox
aarch64-unknown-uefi
aarch64-uwp-windows-msvc
aarch64-wrs-vxworks
aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu
aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32
arm-linux-androideabi
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
arm-unknown-linux-musleabi
arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf
armebv7r-none-eabi
armebv7r-none-eabihf
armv4t-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-musleabi
armv5te-unknown-linux-uclibceabi
armv6-unknown-freebsd
armv6-unknown-netbsd-eabihf
armv6k-nintendo-3ds
armv7-apple-ios
armv7-linux-androideabi
armv7-unknown-freebsd
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-musleabi
armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf
armv7-unknown-netbsd-eabihf
armv7-wrs-vxworks-eabihf
armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabi
armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabihf
armv7a-none-eabi
armv7a-none-eabihf
armv7r-none-eabi
armv7r-none-eabihf
armv7s-apple-ios
asmjs-unknown-emscripten
avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328
bpfeb-unknown-none
bpfel-unknown-none
hexagon-unknown-linux-musl
i386-apple-ios
i586-pc-windows-msvc
i586-unknown-linux-gnu
i586-unknown-linux-musl
i686-apple-darwin
i686-linux-android
i686-pc-windows-gnu
i686-pc-windows-msvc
i686-unknown-freebsd
i686-unknown-haiku
i686-unknown-linux-gnu
i686-unknown-linux-musl
i686-unknown-netbsd
i686-unknown-openbsd
i686-unknown-uefi
i686-uwp-windows-gnu
i686-uwp-windows-msvc
i686-wrs-vxworks
m68k-unknown-linux-gnu
mips-unknown-linux-gnu
mips-unknown-linux-musl
mips-unknown-linux-uclibc
mips64-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mips64-unknown-linux-muslabi64
mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mips64el-unknown-linux-muslabi64
mipsel-sony-psp
mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsel-unknown-linux-musl
mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc
mipsel-unknown-none
mipsisa32r6-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsisa32r6el-unknown-linux-gnu
mipsisa64r6-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
mipsisa64r6el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64
msp430-none-elf
nvptx64-nvidia-cuda
powerpc-unknown-freebsd
powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc-unknown-linux-gnuspe
powerpc-unknown-linux-musl
powerpc-unknown-netbsd
powerpc-unknown-openbsd
powerpc-wrs-vxworks
powerpc-wrs-vxworks-spe
powerpc64-unknown-freebsd
powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc64-unknown-linux-musl
powerpc64-wrs-vxworks
powerpc64le-unknown-freebsd
powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu
powerpc64le-unknown-linux-musl
riscv32gc-unknown-linux-gnu
riscv32gc-unknown-linux-musl
riscv32i-unknown-none-elf
riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf
riscv32imc-esp-espidf
riscv32imc-unknown-none-elf
riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu
riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl
riscv64gc-unknown-none-elf
riscv64imac-unknown-none-elf
s390x-unknown-linux-gnu
s390x-unknown-linux-musl
sparc-unknown-linux-gnu
sparc64-unknown-linux-gnu
sparc64-unknown-netbsd
sparc64-unknown-openbsd
sparcv9-sun-solaris
thumbv4t-none-eabi
thumbv6m-none-eabi
thumbv7a-pc-windows-msvc
thumbv7a-uwp-windows-msvc
thumbv7em-none-eabi
thumbv7em-none-eabihf
thumbv7m-none-eabi
thumbv7neon-linux-androideabi
thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-musleabihf
thumbv8m.base-none-eabi
thumbv8m.main-none-eabi
thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf
wasm32-unknown-emscripten
wasm32-unknown-unknown
wasm32-wasi
wasm64-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin
x86_64-apple-ios
x86_64-apple-ios-macabi
x86_64-apple-tvos
x86_64-fortanix-unknown-sgx
x86_64-fuchsia
x86_64-linux-android
x86_64-pc-solaris
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
x86_64-sun-solaris
x86_64-unknown-dragonfly
x86_64-unknown-freebsd
x86_64-unknown-haiku
x86_64-unknown-hermit
x86_64-unknown-illumos
x86_64-unknown-l4re-uclibc
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnux32
x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
x86_64-unknown-netbsd
x86_64-unknown-none
x86_64-unknown-none-hermitkernel
x86_64-unknown-none-linuxkernel
x86_64-unknown-openbsd
x86_64-unknown-redox
x86_64-unknown-uefi
x86_64-uwp-windows-gnu
x86_64-uwp-windows-msvc
x86_64-wrs-vxworks
`````

Aditional information:

`````
         platform: Linux-4.9.190-perf-g961732a-armv8l-with-libc````
````pip: pip 22.0.3 from /data/data/com.termux/files/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)````
         
setuptools: 60.8.2
         setuptools_rust: 1.1.
`````

Answer (score 0):

Export envirement variable: `export CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=<your system type>`

In this case: `export CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=arm-unknown-linux-androideabi`

But system type arm-unknown-linux-androideabi is not in target-list `rustc --print target-list`

Maybe you can try: `export CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi`